# Galaxy Fold: programmatically turn on the cover screen?

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-fold

How can I programmatically turn on the cover screen (if the phone itself is actually unfolded/opened)?

### Why would I do this?

(Some) Galaxy phones have the ability to charge your wearables via "Wireless PowerShare":

[image]

However, during this operation, the phone itself is unusable since it's facing downwards.

Wireless PowerShare is nice, but devices need to be aligned perfectly, otherwise charging will stop.

If I unfold/open the phone, it turns on the inner screen (and turns off the cover/outer screen), but PowerShare is not stopping, so this phone can charge my devices while being unfolded/opened.

Now, due to this, I would like to find a way to turn on the cover screen while the phone is opened because in this case, I can use it while it keeps charging my devices.

I know this is marginal, but this phone can actually use both displays simultaneously, i.e. during camera (cover screen preview).

So I'm looking for a way to force the cover screen turning back on after I opened the phone.

### Update

I have recorded some Logcat during display switching, and while using both screens:

```
OPEN! (Main screen on, cover screen off)
2021-08-31 21:41:44.085 1107-2429/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] setDualScreenPolicy: dualScreenPolicy: 0 (uid: xxxx pid: yyyy)
2021-08-31 21:41:44.085 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=0

SCREEN DIM/LOCK? (phone is still opened)
2021-08-31 21:42:18.892 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=1, targetInternal=1, dualScreenPolicy=0
2021-08-31 21:42:20.141 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=3, targetInternal=3, dualScreenPolicy=0
2021-08-31 21:42:21.062 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=4, targetInternal=4, dualScreenPolicy=0

CLOSE! (Main screen off, cover screen on)
2021-08-31 21:43:55.490 1107-2429/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] setDualScreenPolicy: dualScreenPolicy: 1 (uid: xxxx pid: yyyy)
2021-08-31 21:43:56.203 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=1, targetInternal=1, dualScreenPolicy=1

SCREEN DIM/LOCK? (phone is closed)
2021-08-31 21:43:57.066 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=3, targetInternal=3, dualScreenPolicy=1
2021-08-31 21:43:58.068 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=4, targetInternal=4, dualScreenPolicy=1
2021-08-31 21:45:26.367 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=1

OPEN! (Main screen on, cover screen off)
2021-08-31 21:45:26.405 1107-2429/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] setDualScreenPolicy: dualScreenPolicy: 0 (uid: xxxx pid: yyyy)
2021-08-31 21:46:44.788 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=0

Use the camera app, which uses both screens (i.e. Main screen: ON, cover screen: ON)
2021-08-31 21:46:49.598 1107-1680/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] setDualScreenPolicy: dualScreenPolicy: -1 (uid: xxxx pid: yyyy)
2021-08-31 21:46:49.598 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=-1

Quit the camera app (Main screen: ON, cover screen: OFF)
2021-08-31 21:47:08.283 1107-2429/? D/PowerManagerService: [api] setDualScreenPolicy: dualScreenPolicy: 1 (uid: xxxx pid: yyyy)
2021-08-31 21:47:08.283 1107-1787/? D/DisplayPowerController: animateScreenStateChange: target=2, targetInternal=2, dualScreenPolicy=1
```

Comment: I doubt we have a lot users here own such toys, you should provide more information about phone

Comment: What kind of information would help more?

Comment: Maybe logcat or dumpsys or getevent record from switching on display, idk anything that could help

Comment: I have added some logcats, which is quite promising.

Comment: So dualScreenPolicy=1 is what you want. comments in source code sometimes give hints, check DisplayPowerController.java

Comment: Yes, but `DisplayPowerController.java` doesn't have this `dualScreenPolicy`, at least what I have found in Android sources. :(

Comment: check automation apps like macrodroid, tasker etc maybe they already added display options for multiscreen devices

Comment: In display it only displays the cover screen. In sensors, there is one: `com.samsung.sensor.folding_angle`. I believe it uses this one to detect if it's actually folded or unfolded. But how can I proceed from this point?

Comment: looks like you might able to simulate intent with (am) activity manager